# Why am I getting "no main class found"?

Tags: java

I simply tried running a simple Java applet using `extends Applet` and `extends JApplet` too as suggested when I searched for it on Google.
I am still getting the error:

> no main class found

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Applets don't have a main method. You need to load them via the applet viewer or web plugin with a browser...

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20601920/2587435). It may help you out if you're using NetBeans

Answer (score 1):

Applets don't have a main method, you need to load applets by **appletviewer** or in a **browser**

**for example:**

```
<APPLET CODEBASE="../classes/" ARCHIVE="your_jar.jar" 
         CODE=DemoApplet.class WIDTH=140 HEIGHT=45>
    <PARAM NAME="HELPURL" VALUE="help.htm">
</APPLET>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remebemer `java.awt.Applet` need a `run`,`paint` and `destroy` methods, I tested some `Applets` on `ReadyToProgram` long years ago.