# Running a JPanel Form

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, gui-builder

I am beginner in java. I created a `JPanel` form in java (NetBeans). then, i defined some actions such as mathematical calculations. When i ran my project, i did not get any error, but i could not see the `JPanel` form in the running time. because i did not define jform in main class. how can i define `JPanel` form in main class to show me `JPanel` form in running time.

```
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {


    public NewJPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jLabel1.setText("First Number:");

        jLabel2.setText("Second Number:");

        jLabel3.setText("Result:");

        jButton1.setText("Add");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Subtract");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Multiply");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Divide");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("Clear");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(66, 66, 66)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 69, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(27, 27, 27))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addGap(88, 88, 88)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 77, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(120, 120, 120)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                        .addComponent(jButton5)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jButton5))
                .addContainerGap(67, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        double num1, num2, result;
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
        result = num1 + num2;
        jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        double num1, num2, result;
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
        result = num1 - num2;
        jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        double num1,num2, result;
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
        result = num1*num2;
        jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        double num1, num2, result;
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
        result = num1 / num2;

    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTextField1.setText("");
        jTextField2.setText("");
        jTextField3.setText("");
    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JPanel` is not a runnable class without a top-level container like `JFrame` and you need a `main` method. Instead of creating `JPanel` form, you should have created a `JFrame` form that has a `main` method auto-generated for you. It looks like you are using Netbeans GUI Builder. Just open a new `JFrame` form. And you can just add the `JPanel` form to the `JFrame` form.

With NetBeans desing view, you can just drag and drop your `JPanel` form to you `JFrame` form, as seen [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194357/2587435)

Also to explicitly specify the Main class of a project, see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20601920/2587435)

Comment: @Jason I don't get a 404. The question was deleted and can only be seen by high rep users. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
JFrame frameName = new JFrame();
frameName.setVisible(true);

//Now add your JPanel (JPanel yourJPanelName = new JPanel();)
frameName.add(yourJPanelName);
```

You can work with JFrame.