# Netbeans IDE 11 cannot access java.lang Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Tags: java, netbeans-11

I downloaded netbeans ide 11 and tried to do a sample hello world project but it is giving me error "cannot access java.lang
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath"
I tried some solutions from stack overflow but didnt worked.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication1;

/**
 *
 * @author ahmad
 */
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    
}
```

### Main error is
" cannot access java.lang
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

"[image]

Comment: Please update your question with a screen shot of **Tools > Java Platforms**.

Answer (score 14):

I also had the same issue.
Solved using manually setting the default jdk.

1. open the `netbeans.conf` from `<install_dir>/netbeans/etc`
2. set the JDK home path for `netbeans_jdkhome` property

I am using `Ubuntu 19.10`

Comment: If you are not sure of your JDK path, run `sudo update-java-alternatives -l` to list these. Also, make sure you have set a Main Class as an entry point under Project Properties. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601845/no-main-class-found-in-netbeans

Answer (score 7):

After exiting netbeans edit the config file `netbeans.conf` using

```html
nano ~/netbeans-11.2/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf
```

In the line `netbeans_jdkhome` edit the path like

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

(Found at [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166639/cant-using-netbeans-10-0-after-installing-from-repository-on-ubuntu-18-04))

Answer (score 3):

After a complete uninstall of my distros Netbeans version, I resorted to installing  Netbeans 11 LTS version from the https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/nb110.html  into /usr/share/netbeans. This seems to have resolved the issues in the IDE. The program also seems to compile and run faster now.

I was having very similar problems with Netbeans IDE from the Ubunutu/Mint repositories which was still on version 10 the open JDK was version 11. I could not get the IDE to display without errors - but the program would compile and run from the command line fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Maven for the project and OpenJDK the reason could be the way that you define the source and target options in the maven-compiler-plugin. I had a little project build with JDK 1.8 and when I migrated it the maven compiler plugin show me that error.
The solution that worked for me was change the format of the java version on the **source** and **target** parameters in maven-compiler-plugin definition:

Before:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <compilerArguments>
            <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
        </compilerArguments>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>7</source>
        <target>7</target>
        <compilerArguments>
            <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
        </compilerArguments>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. First create a folder > install Jdk in this folder > create a new folder inside your first creating folder > install netbeans second creating folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, always check the JDK version and all the libraries the project uses